# Pandas, matplotlib, would like to add on the graph some annotations like "mean", "variance", etc

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am rather new to Python 2.7 and Pandas. I have a bar graph and would like to add annotations like `mean`, `variance`, etc. I already computed above in the graph. My current graph looks like this:

[image]

Along with this line of code:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.title('All the observation', fontsize=16)
matplotlib.pyplot.annotate( mean, ( 0 , 0), ( 0, 14000), fontsize=16)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Does someone have any idea on how to add on the graph the mean etc in a proper and nice way?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Best,
Viktor

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.figtext(.6, .8, "Mean = {}".format(mean))
```

If you have more values to add:

```
plt.figtext(.6, .8, "Mean = {}\nVariance = {}".format(mean, variance))
```

[image]

Ps. usually matplotlib.pyplot is imported in this way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: I would also suggest using some string formatting: `"Mean = {:.3f}".format(mean)` to make the digit display a little easier to handle. I also wouldn't use boxplots, generally, there's a ton of good reasons not to.

Comment: Yes thanks it works perfectly! thank you!